# how can I create a custom SSRS report shape?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, reporting-services-map

I'm trying to create a simple SSRS map report in visual studio. I was using the built in map functionality to create one but I need to create custom regions that I will then overlay over a bitmap image of the US. How can i go about creating these custom regions? I need them to be dynamically colored based on sales data. Really lost, so I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For custom shapes, you either need to acquire the shape as an ESRI file or convert the shape to a SQL Server spatial data polygon. I have some tips here:

http://blog.datainspirations.com/2010/05/11/sql-server-2008-r2-reporting-services-the-word-is-but-a-stage-t-sql-tuesday-006/

http://blog.datainspirations.com/2011/03/24/multi-state-maps-in-reporting-services/

Bottom line - your only options are the built-in maps of the US, ESRI Shapefile, or SQL Server spatial data.

Comment: Hmm, thank you. Do you by any chance know of any good tools that can convert vector images into ESRI format? That would be super helpful.

Comment: I don't know what kind of vector image you're using, but here's a converter that will produce an ESRI SHP file: http://converter.mygeodata.eu/#convertVector