# creating map report in SSRS. In which on click of particular area it should go to that area map in same report

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to create map report of us state. When I click on perticular state  it should display only that state in same report. 
Can somebody help me. 
Thanks

Comment: Google "SSRS Image Map"

Comment: I have googled it. But not getting how get selected state in same report

Comment: Try contacting the guy who asked this question, he seems to have solved it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851656/how-can-i-create-a-custom-ssrs-report-shape